# Binary Code to String

Tags: lua

I am playing Feed The Beast and would like to create a network. I can already send binary codes from one computer to another. The method to get a binary code out of a string is the following:

```
function toBinString(s)
  bytes = {string.byte(s,i,string.len(s))}
  binary = ""

  for i,number in ipairs(bytes) do
    c = 0

    while(number>0) do
      binary = (number%2)..binary
      number = number - (number%2)
      number = number/2
      c = c+1
    end

    while(c<8) do
      binary = "0"..binary
      c = c+1
    end
  end

  return binary
end

function toBin(s)
  binary = toBinString(s)    
  ret = {}
  c = 1

  for i=1,string.len(binary) do
    char = string.sub(binary,i,i)

    if(tonumber(char)==0) then
      ret[c] = 0
      c = c+1
    elseif(tonumber(char)==1) then
      ret[c] = 1
      c = c+1
    elseif(tonumber(char)) then
      print("Error: expected \'0\' or \'1\' but got \'",char,"\'.")
    end
  end

  return ret
end
```

How can I get the string that was used in `string.byte(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
function toBinAndBack(s)
  local bin = toBin(s)
  local r = {}
  for i=1,#bin,8 do
    local n = 0
    for j=0,7 do
      n = n + (2^(7-j)) * bin[i+j]
    end
    r[#r+1] = n
  end
  return string.char(unpack(r)):reverse()
end
```

The `reverse` at the end is needed because you encode the strings in reverse in `toBinString`. Also, I had to replace this line: `bytes = {string.byte(s,i,string.len(s))}` by `bytes = {string.byte(s,1,-1)}` to make your code work.

Note that using `unpack()` limits the size of the string that can be decoded. If you want to decode arbitrarily long strings, you can replace the last line (`return string.char(unpack(r)):reverse()`) by this:

```
for i=1,#r do
  r[i] = string.char(r[i])
end
return table.concat(r):reverse()
```

Comment: about the `bytes = ...` thing: it worked for me (in-game) so I had no problems :D Anyway, I am going to use your code :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: In `bytes = ...` the `string.len(s)` is probably OK, but `i` has never been defined before. It must come from some other part of your code I guess :)

Comment: Could be, yes. I think that Ctrl+C was the cause of that `i` being there :D